# Indexing an NSMutableDictiobary?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have an NSMutableDictionary which holds objects of string type like this:

```
{
    {
        {"ID":"23"},
        {"NAME":"Ted"}
    },
    {
        {"ID":"46"},
        {"NAME":"Karren"}
    },
    {
        {"ID":"6"},
        {"NAME":"Phillip"}
    }
}
```

I need a way to access object with ID #x in an indexed manner.
Now, since the object with ID=46 is in index #1
I need a way to make the dictionary still have it's objects in their index as it is, but is it possible to add a key to that object?
Like:

```
"6":"{
   {"ID":"6"},
   {"NAME":"Phillip"}
}"
```

If possible to show some code.
Otherwise, how can I do that another way.
Thanks

Comment: Can you do something with that structure. You should have an array of dictionaries. Can you confirm about this? Something like this would be more appropriate [JSON Structure](http://pastebin.com/PVxRwTJy)

Comment: It's stupid to structure the JSON like this: `{{"ID":"23"}, {"NAME":"Ted"}}`.  Rather it should like this:  `{"ID":"23", "NAME":"Ted"}` -- Place related items in the same JSON object.  Who is defining this JSON syntax???

Answer (score 0):

What about using predicates ?

```
NSArray *resultArray = [[[myDictionary allValues] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ID == %@", @"6"]];
```

you retrieve all your dictionary values, and use a predicate to return a single element array with the value you were looking for

(code not tested but should work)

Comment: but if the dictionary key is always the same as your "ID", I don't see the point

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to do something with the strucutre,

```
[
    {
        "ID": 23,
        "Name": "Ted"
    },
    {
        "ID": 46,
        "Name": "Karen"
    },
    {
        "ID": 6,
        "Name": "Philip"
    }
]
```

This would make your work a lot easier. You can search/sort it based on `ID` or `Name` easily.

```
//All users array
NSArray *users = ....

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ID = %d",userID];

//Find User against a user id
NSDictionary *user = [[users filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] lastObject];
```

Comment: Don't you mean "search", not "sort"?

Comment: @HotLicks I meant both, it's easier to create a sortDescriptor with ID or Name. And also easy to search by predicate.